# Error: Could not mmap file: vmlinux

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

In a newly installed virtual machine I get this error when compiling the kernel for the x86 architecture:

```
$ Could not mmap file: vmlinux

$ make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

It is the first time I see it. 
I have increased the size of `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` to 128MB, but it does not solve the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue when compiling kernel in virtual box shared folder. Error comes from `mmap_file()` function in source file `scripts/sortextable.c`.
Moreover, all **mmap** functions failed with **errno** EINVAL within shared folder.

I fixed it with copying linux sources into non shared folder like */home/Name/linux* and compiled there.

Comment: Same for me on Parallels Desktop.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem compiling linux kernel on the VirtualBox shared folder here and I make a little fix in the function sortextable at line 104 (+/-) of script link-vmlinux.sh localized in scripts/ directory

I change this:

```
sortextable()
{
        ${objtree}/scripts/sortextable ${1}        
}
```

for this:

```
sortextable()
{
    cp ${1} /tmp/.${1}
    scripts/sortextable /tmp/.${1}
    cp /tmp/.${1} ${1}
}
```

And works for me!

Comment: What does this actually do?

Comment: Just only a patch in shell script to solve the problem of function execution in a specific file. Only uses a trick to execute this execution on /tmp directory. As I said, this works for me!

Comment: This also worked for me. Much simpler solution that moving the entire source to a native VM folder.

Comment: Nice idea, but I got `sortextable not found`. Maybe the script path needs to be adjusted.

Comment: why not `${objtree}scripts/sortextable /tmp/.${1}`? That should work

Comment: I just faced this problem building px4 project under libvirt ubuntu vm.  The expanded solution (posted by Alan) seemed to work for me, while the condensed solution (by user1593842) did not.  Not sure why, but that's my empirical result.

Comment: stackoverflow is awesome.  And so is this workaround.

Comment: Encounter this issue while compiling 5.11.16 on Debian 10 VM in a shared folder. This solution worked for me too. Though I didn't find `sortextable()` in the script. I think its renamed to `sorttable()`.